# Is there convergence in the following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am unable to figure out $\displaystyle \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ . Any help would be appreciated,Thanks

Comment: The series diverges.

Comment: It is likely that there is a typo in the formula in the question.  As written, the expression being summed over $n$ does not depend on $n$.  This makes the series divergent for _any_ value of $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\epsilon} = \lim_{N \to +\infty} \frac{N}{\epsilon} = +\infty.$$

At the end:

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\epsilon} = +\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\epsilon} = \frac{1}{\epsilon}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1 = \frac{1}{\epsilon}*{\infty}$

Well, as $\epsilon$ is always positive $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ is always positive so $\frac{1}{\epsilon}*{\infty}$ is always $\infty$. So ...